# QString and QByteArray memory usage

Tags: c++, qt

The QByteArray documentation states that it is to be used when memory conservation is critical.  I've been working on a class (FieldName) that keeps an internal store of commonly used QString's so that when two FieldName objects are compared for equality, a quick integer comparison is done.

My thinking was that I could save some memory and gain speed by using QByteArray instead of QString since I only need standard ASCII characters.  But when I change out the QString in the following code for QByteArray, my tests show that speed is increased, but memory usage more than doubles.  This runs counter to the documentation.

```
#ifndef H_FIELDNAME
#define H_FIELDNAME

#include <QString>

class FieldName
{
   public:
      FieldName() : mKey(0) { init(); }
      FieldName(const QString& s);
      const QString& constString() const;
      bool operator==(const FieldName& other) const { return mKey == other.mKey; }
      bool operator!=(const FieldName& other) const { return mKey != other.mKey; }
   private:
      int mKey;
      void init();
      int findKey(const QString& s);
};

#endif
```

CPP file:

```
#include "fieldname.h"
// #include <QMutex> // demo version not thread-safe
#include <QVector>

static QVector<QString*> FieldName__List;
static bool FieldName__FirstCall(true);

FieldName::FieldName(const QString& s)
{
   init();
   mKey = findKey(s);
}

const QString& FieldName::constString() const
{
   return(*FieldName__List.at(mKey));
}

void FieldName::init()
{
   if(FieldName__FirstCall)
   {
      if(FieldName__List.isEmpty())
      {
         FieldName__List.append(new QString(""));
         FieldName__FirstCall = false;
      }
   }
}

int FieldName::findKey(const QString& s)
{
   if(s.isEmpty())
      return 0;
   int sz(FieldName__List.size());
   for(int idx=1; idx<sz; ++idx)
   {
      if(s == *FieldName_List.at(idx))
         return idx;
   }
   FieldName__List.append(new QString(s));
   return(FieldName__List.size() - 1);
}
```

Can anyone let me know what I may be doing that is causing this to use more memory when I substitute QByteArray for QString in the above class?

Testcode:

```
QStringList qsl; // filled with 84000 unique English words
FieldName fn;
foreach(QString s, qsl)
{
   fn = FieldName(s);
   // do stuff here
}
```

Comment: Note that you need to be careful not to cause QByteArray's (that are implicitly shared) to be copied (internally), for example when obtaining non-const references (`std::as_const` can come in quite handy sometimes - when iterating for example).

Comment: I have a hunch that your test for the string version uses string constants. Is that the case?

Comment: Added testcode.  I'm unable to use C++17 at this time.  Using Qt 5.8 opensource on Windows.

Comment: Note that both QString and QByteArray are essentially pointers to shared data, copy-on-write. Do not allocate them with new, and probably don't use QVector of pointers to them. Just use them as values. That alone will save you a lot of overhead.